# BottomNavigationView reduce size after click an BottomNavView item?

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

When I click on bottom nav item, BottomNavigationView size automatically reduce. It only happen when control transfer from home item to any other item. When I click on any other item third time, it's automatically back up to it's original size.

. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  . .

```
 BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav_view);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                Fragment selectedFragment = null;


                switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.home_bottom_nav:
                        selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.game_bottom_nav:
                        selectedFragment = new GameFragment();
//                        selectedFragment = GameFragment.newInstance("Para1","Para2");
                        break;
                    case R.id.even_bottom_nav:
                        selectedFragment = new EventFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.profile_bottom_nav:
                        selectedFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                        break;
                }

                assert selectedFragment != null;
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentLayout,selectedFragment)
                        .commit();

                return true;
            }
        });

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentLayout,new HomeFragment()).commit();
```

XML code

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/Widget.BottomNavigationView"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_items" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: share codes where onClick is handled of navigation view

Comment: please share your code

Comment: I just update the code.

Comment: post your layout xml content as well.

Comment: Sir Zoe after your comment, I'm not enable to post any other question. Can you remove the ban. I use the tag because I think it's relevant. I think their should be a warning. Directly ban does not make any sense and they say I will be able to ask another question after 6 month that a huge time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/Widget.BottomNavigationView"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_items"

        app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"
        app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/Widget.BottomNavigationView"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
 />
```

Comment: Android resource linking failed
It generate Error: C:\Users\AbdullahPC\AndroidStudioProjects\MyProjects\PAKChoice\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_home.xml:19: error: attribute itemTextAppearanceInActive (aka com.example.pakchoice:itemTextAppearanceInActive) not found.
error: failed linking file resources.

Comment: Sorry! It should be app:itemTextAppearanceInactive. Try again

Comment: Oh man. It's work. Thanks. Can you tell me the reason. Why it decrease the size in inactivite  state.

Comment: Sir can you vote this question. They ban me from asking question due to negative vote from someone.

Comment: Just follow the best practice. When active is set, inactive should be set also. Otherwise, the value of inactive property will be set to some sort of default value which you can not control and causing weird behavior.

Answer (score 0):

can you please cross check your BottomNavigaionView as this: use wrap_content and alignParentBottom. Try changing your FrameLayout height to wrap_content and remove this line app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_buttom_navigation" />
```

Comment: To ensure that your layout is flexible and adapts to different screen sizes, you should use "wrap_content"  for height , instead of hard-coded sizes.

Comment: android:layout_height="56dp"; this height value is recommended by documentation.

Comment: check your FrameLayout which has same attributes as BottomNavigationView  
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" make sure to make it above the BottomNavigation only

Answer (score 0):

> Change your xml bottomnavigation and framlayout width 0dp. Also give bottomnavigation top constraint and height wrap_content.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/Widget.BottomNavigationView"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fragmentLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_items" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I check it but program behave same.

Comment: It only change the size when control shift from home. When I click third time, size back to original.

Comment: yes got it I am also faced same issue before. let me check again

Comment: I did not understand. What you mean by this "in code added in all tab still now?"

Comment: oops sorry, in third tab any layout added?

Comment: I did not change any thing in third tab layout. It's default code.

Comment: I just post pic. I think it will help to understand problem.